# AS3 How to add multiple childs to stage without copying and pasting code

Tags: actionscript-3

I am adding 1 cowboy to the stage each time i run the program. I want there to be 5 cowboys on the stage when i run the program. I know that i can copy and paste the code 4 times but i was wondering if there was a shorter and quicker way to do this.

Here's my code

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Callum Singh
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var gun:crosshair;
        public var cowboy:enemy;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            gun = new crosshair();
            stage.addChild (gun);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCrosshair);

            cowboy = new enemy();
            cowboy.x = Math.random() * 600;
            cowboy.y = Math.random() * 400;
            stage.addChild(cowboy);
            cowboy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleShoot);

        }

        private function moveCrosshair(e:Event):void
        {
            gun.x = mouseX -120;
            gun.y = mouseY -115;
            Mouse.hide();

        }

        private function handleShoot(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.target == cowboy)
                {
                    cowboy.visible = false;
                }   
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: have you considered using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Iggy is correct, it will not work as you would expect based on the rest of your code. If left alone, it would still get 5 cowboys but only create 1 cowboy reference. `cowboy` is a class variable and performing his code will only overwrite the cowboy variable each time through the loop.

You need to hold each cowboy instances. The base way is to store them into an Array or Vector. You could also reference them by name (if you were setting it) as well. Taking your code from above, here are only the adjustments taking both options into account.

```
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var gun:crosshair;
        public var cowboys:Array;  // Array to hold all your cowboys

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            gun = new crosshair();
            stage.addChild (gun);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCrosshair);

            cowboys = new Array();

            for(var i:uint = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                var cowboy:enemy = new enemy();
                cowboy.x = Math.random() * 600;
                cowboy.y = Math.random() * 400;
                cowboy.name = "cowboy" + i; // assuming that your enemy class extends DisplayObject types
                stage.addChild(cowboy);
                cowboy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleShoot);
                cowboys.push(cowboy);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! The adjustments have created 5 cowboys to appear on the screen but now I am having trouble that when you click them they don't disappear. Could you possibly explain why?

Comment: private function handleShoot(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        e.target.visible = false;  
    }

Comment: Because cowboy does not exist any more. You now have an Array of cowboys. In any case `e` returns an Event object that allows you access to the target of the click event (the cowboy clicked) and you just need to set its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Basic for loop should do the trick.

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cowboy = new enemy();
    cowboy.x = Math.random() * 600;
    cowboy.y = Math.random() * 400;
    stage.addChild(cowboy);
    cowboy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleShoot);
}
```